# cerrar app de navegación desde otra aplicacion

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un botón en una actividad que se muestra cuando el usuario entra en una pagina pornográfica, el problema es que cuando el usuario opriba ese boton debera cerrar esa actividad pero también necesito cerrar las actividades del navegador también.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                                String urlco= url_codificada(url1);
                                startBrowserf("http://localhost:5358/"+urlco);
                                Bloqueo();
                            } else{
                                String urlco= url_codificada(url1);
                                startBrowserf("http://localhost:5358/"+urlco);
                            }
```

este es el metodo startbrowserf

```
  private void startBrowserf(String url) {
    Browser browser = Browser.browsers.get(2);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(1082130436);
    intent.addFlags(-4194305);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html");
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(browser.getPackage(), browser.getActivity()));
    intent.putExtra("com.android.browser.application_id", browser.getPackage());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Como muestras la actividad cuando el usuario entra a una pagina porn? porque no agregas el código.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys Disculpa ya agregue el llamado y el método para aclarar como funciona por el momento.